# Error from server (BadRequest): container "mariadb" in pod is waiting to start: CreateContainerConfigError

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, mariadb

This Helm chart (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/wordpress ) should install WordPress on Kubernetes with:

`helm install stable/wordpress`

However, I get:

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS                       RESTARTS   AGE
wp-1-mariadb-0                   0/1     CreateContainerConfigError   0          30m
wp-1-wordpress-7bff96d46-4bss6   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff             8          30m
```

and

```
k logs wp-1-mariadb-0
Error from server (BadRequest): container "mariadb" in pod "wp-1-mariadb-0" is waiting to start: CreateContainerConfigError
```

and

```
kubectl describe pod wp-1-mariadb-0
Normal   Pulled                 5s (x5 over 48s)  kubelet, minikube  Container image "docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.1.36-debian-9" already present on machine
Warning  Failed                 5s (x5 over 48s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: failed to prepare subPath for volumeMount "config" of container "mariadb"
```

Any suggestions what the problem might be?

Comment: Can you show output of `kubectl describe pod wp-1-mariadb-0`? There might be some events which can help.

Comment: @EmruzHossain good call. Related to this? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61076